# Move the index of a selection into a text field when press submit

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I want to copy the index of a selection into a text field when the submit button is pressed. For example, I want to copy the name 'Accountant' of an option in the selection list into a textbox when I choose the option.
This is the HTML:

```
<form action = "">
    <select name = "job_term_cat">
      <option value="----">--Select--</option>
      <option value="roma">Accountant</option>
      <option value="torino">Cashier</option>
      <option value="milan">Lawyer</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="job_title" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript I thought going to work for submit button, it returns no index of the option that is clicked.

```
<p><input type="submit" 
onclick="var s= this.form.element[job_term_cat]; 
    this form.elements[job_title].value= s.options[s.selectedIndex].textContent"
class="submit" name="job_submit" 
value="<?php _e('Next &rarr;', 'myapp'); ?>"  /></p>
```

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean?  Were you getting an error, was the output not correct, if not, what *was* the output for this example.  If you got an error, what was it, where did it occur, etc.

Comment: You are expecting me to give the error I saw about FIVE MONTH AGO, that is really constructive of you

Comment: Sure.  It's not like you need to remember.  You should be able to replicate the problem.  The point is that you shouldn't be expecting the readers to do all of that work for you; you should be doing it yourself.  We also shouldn't be guessing what the problem is, even if it seems obvious to you; it should be explicit.

Comment: @Servy, so for whoever just voted down, explain yourself further. There is no reason to regenerate the issue again while the perfect answer has been found. the vote down is not justified.

Comment: @Adam thats what happens when you post an "im question banned" on meta; people give advise on how to improve your questions, assume you take that advise and look through your questions upvoting and downvoting as appropriate. In all the other cases ive seen (even where only minimal effort has been made) this has had a possitive effect and the q ban ends. Please note also that question quality is entirely unaffected by answer quality

Comment: @Richard Tingle This is the so far the most fix I could remember what had going on with this problem. Thats the best I could fix, I dont want to lie about what is the problem, which is wasting time for both readers and me.

Comment: @Adam Indeed, making up a pretend problem is of course pointless, people do obscess about showing what you've tried yourself (which is important) but i'm much more interested in a question being clear. This question seems quite clear now. The "after clicking it" helps add context, I have upvoted

Comment: @Richard Tingle, I do not know how clear could it get. Seem people don't really review it afterward even I edit it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s= this.form.elements['job_term_cat'];
```

(mind the s in elements and the quotes)

```
this form.elements['job_title'].value= s.options[s.selectedIndex].textContent;
```

(mind the quotes)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if OP wanted to get selectedIndex or selected option's textContent - notice the question's thread

Answer (score 1):

well, you have some errors in your syntax, for example not `var s= this.form.element[job_term_cat];` but `var s= this.form.elements[job_term_cat];`

here is the working code:

**EDIT: I misplaced some names, check this:**

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="this.form.elements['job_title'].value = this.form.elements['job_term_cat'].selectedIndex" class="submit" name="job_submit" value="<?php _e('Next &rarr;', 'myapp'); ?>"  /></p>
```

Comment: Hello :) thanks! But it shows 1,2,3, instead of the actual name of accountant, lawyer and such, do you know why?

Comment: oh wait the textContent fixed it, but ....another issue I have a issue with this code

Comment: $dropdown = str_replace('class=\'job_cat\' >','class=\'job_cat\' ><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);                                   what does it means?because when the value is attached, the "select a category... always follow the indexContent selected.

Comment: nvm it worked according to Rieck's answer, but still thanks!